# Why is "concat" not working for me? It gives undefined error

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I tried to concat three arrays into one ("producto"), but when I call it with "console.table(producto)" it returns "undefined". I'm not sure why.

```
class Producto {
    constructor(nombre, precio) {
        this.nommbre= nombre;
        this.precio = parseFloat(precio);
    }

    descuento20() {
        this.precio = this.precio * 0.10;
    }
}

const productos = []
const snacks = []
const candy = []
const drinks = []

function combinarPaises () {
    const productos = snacks.concat(candy, drinks);
    console.table(productos);
}

snacks.push(new Producto("Befco Kuriyama Bakauke Rice Crackers", "140.67"));
candy.push(new Producto("Kikko Seika Potted Grape Candy", "101.67"));
drinks.push(new Producto("Calpico Drink", "149.66"));
```

Comment: `const productos` inside `combinarPaises` is a different variable to `const productos = [];` outside that function (which you never call anyway)

Comment: This is working fine for me. (I have to add a line to call `combinarPaises()` at the end, and I have to open the actual console to see the table because it won't display on StackOverflow's console)

Comment: at a guess, the OP code does `productos = combinarPaises ()`

Comment: If you call the function at the end, the table ends up in the console just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/x9f8Lcr2/ You need to put a proper [mre] in the question

Comment: your function  combinarPaises need to return productos, otherwise your code is working just fine